# Bootstrap-TagsInput confirmKeys don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I can't get the default Bootstrap-TagsInput `confirmKeys`, namely `enter` = `13` or `comma` = `188`, to work out of the box. This is true with or without [Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events). Confirm keys allow you to create a tag by clicking that key.

I think the issue is whether or not the tags are strings or objects. If you look at [the Tagsinput demo](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), the "Typeahead" example allows tag creation with the default `confirmKeys`, `enter` or `comma`, but the "Objects as Tags" example right below it does not.

Any idea how to make the `confirmKeys` work with object tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to edited Bootstrap-tagsinput library to make this work.

Here's what I added/commented out in the library:

```
 //self.options.freeInput = false; //notice commented out

//... (lots of lines between)

if (self.options.freeInput && (keyCombinationInList(event, self.options.confirmKeys) || maxLengthReached)) {
    // Only attempt to add a tag if there is data in the field

    if (text.length !== 0) {
       //<<<<< BEGIN code block added
       //self.add(maxLengthReached ? text.substr(0, self.options.maxChars) : text); //notice commented out

       var item2 = self.$input.val();
       if (self.objectItems) {
         var beforeFreeInputItemAdd = $.Event('beforeFreeInputItemAdd', { item: item2, cancel: true });
         self.$element.trigger(beforeFreeInputItemAdd);
         if (beforeFreeInputItemAdd.cancel)
           return;

         item2 = beforeFreeInputItemAdd.item;
       }

       self.add(item2);
       self.$input.val(''); 
       //  $input.val(''); //>>>>>> END code block added
    }

}
```

And then to anywhere in one's codebase that wants to make use of this library modification I added this:

```
var id_increment = 1;
$("#my-tagsinput-field").on('beforeFreeInputItemAdd', function(event) {

    event.item = {'name': event.item, 'id': 'new-'+id_increment};
    event.cancel = false;
    id_increment++;

});
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, your change made it in, but it's currently undocumented.

Comment: Scratch that, they were overwritten once it got merged, unless I'm a dummy and can't make it work. :( Would have been great.

Comment: event.item = {'name': event.item, 'id': 'new-'+id_increment}; -> I don't think this is proper because you add an object to the name property. This will make the tagsinput show an [Object object] tag in your input.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solutions was have *freeInput* in the configuration, e.g.

```
$( 'input[type="tags"]' ).tagsinput(
{
    typeaheadjs: [{
        minLength: 1,
        highlight: true
    },
    {
        limit: 99,
        name: type,
        displayKey: 1,
        valueKey: 'name',
        source: sourcefunc,
        templates: { suggestion: suggestionsfunc }
    }],
    freeInput: true
});
```

And in the tagsinput source code change the following to *false*.

```
cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty: false,
```

This is on line 24 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Year 2022, Bootstrap version 2.3.1:

https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

put this code:

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  confirmKeys: [13, 44, 32]
});
```

inside the `<script>`, but outside `$(document).ready({...`

Keys: 13 - Enter; 44 - comma; 32 - spacebar.

You shuold also change `$('input')` to `$('your_input_class_or_id')` and don't forget # or . at the start `$('#your_...` or `$('.your_...`